# MissingMethodException Serilog.Context.LogContext.Push

Tags: c#, serilog, microsoft-extensions-logging

I did some [consolidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#consolidate-tab) of my NuGet packages across my solution and now I'm receiving:

*exception message:*

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.IDisposable Serilog.Context.LogContext.Push(Serilog.Core.ILogEventEnricher)'.

*call stack on the exception:*

> at Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLoggerProvider.BeginScope[T](T state)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.BeginScope[TState](TState state)

when I make a call like this:

```cs
using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["SomeProperty"] = someVariable,
}))
{
    logger.LogInfo("hello world");
}
```

*package.config*

```xml
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Serilog" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
```

It would seem I have an incorrect NuGet reference but I'm not seeing it.

I also put together a [full repro of the problem here](https://github.com/spottedmahn/experiments-2020/tree/master/Serilog%20Client%20Info%20Enricher%20Debug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, the issue is with the package [Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo/1.1.2) including an old version of `Serilog.dll` within the NuGet package, which is wrong (as it's supposed to be a dependency via NuGet only), thus the long-term fix is the maintainer fix that [as you reported](https://github.com/mo-esmp/serilog-enrichers-clientinfo/issues/6).

A short-term fix, would be to manually edit your `.csproj` file to use the correct `Serilog.dll`, from the Serilog package:

```
<Reference Include="Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Serilog.2.10.0\lib\net46\Serilog.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Your [repro project](https://github.com/spottedmahn/experiments-2020/blob/89d9a0d73072750a64a6271c438069c4dbe6e207/Serilog%20Client%20Info%20Enricher%20Debug/Serilog%20Client%20Info%20Enricher%20Debug/Serilog%20Client%20Info%20Enricher%20Debug.csproj#L76-L78) is pointing to the `Serilog.dll` that is inside of the [Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo/1.1.2) package:

```
<Reference Include="Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo.1.1.2\lib\net452\Serilog.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

You can also add a post-build step that always copies the correct `Serilog.dll` to the output folder of your project.

---

**Update**: This has been fixed in [Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo v1.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo/1.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

[Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo/) is including `Serilog v2.4.0.0`, an old version, with their NuGet package:

[image: screenshot of serilog dll included with nuget package]

I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/mo-esmp/serilog-enrichers-clientinfo/issues/6) on the GitHub project.

Comment: If you add a reference to your project directly to Serilog, everything should work.

Comment: Hi @NicholasBlumhardt - I have a reference to Serilog, not sure why that's not working ‍♂️.  I put together a [repro here](https://github.com/spottedmahn/experiments-2020/tree/master/Serilog%20Client%20Info%20Enricher%20Debug).  I would love your input on this!